# Kendall's Tau-b Critical values

Tags: hypothesis-testing, kendall-tau

I want to interpret Kendall's Tau-b z-score values. For large enough sample sizes, its distribution is probably normal and there isn't a problem. But for small sample sizes, I want to know if there is a critical values table I can use. Is there a difference between such a table for Tau-a and Tau-b?